# Adding calculated column to pivot table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table like the following

```
Item Name | Date       | Previous Data | Updated Data
Unit 1    | 1-Jul-2013 | 500           | 550 
Unit 1    | 1-Aug-2013 | 550           | 550
Unit 1    | 1-Sep-2013 | 450           | 600 
Unit 1    | 1-Oct-2013 | 600           | 550
```

Using the pivot function, I have them presented like the following:

```
Title     | Jul | Aug   | Sep | Oct
Prev. Data| 500 | 550   | 450 | 600
Upd. Data | 550 | 550   | 600 | 550
```

Now, here's the tricky part that I want to achieve. The Prev. Data are keyed in beforehand as a way of forecasting. When the actual month comes, only then that we key in Upd. Data.

I want to add another column called YTD (year to date) next to the last month (i.e Dec) that calculated the weighted average for each of the category. Let's say we're now in October, the weighted average calculation method would be

```
YTD = (Jan*(#Days in Jan) + Feb*(#Days in Feb) + ... + Oct*(#Days in Oct))/(Total days in a year)
```

Currently, my query looks like the following;

```
Select col,
[1] as Jan,
[2] Feb,
[3] Mar,
[4] Apr,
[5] May,
[6] Jun,
[7] Jul,
[8] Aug,
[9] Sep,
[10] Oct,
[11] Nov,
[12] Dec, 
(isnull([1],0)+isnull([2],0)+isnull([3],0))/3 as Q1, 
(isnull([4],0)+isnull([5],0)+isnull([6],0))/3 as Q2, 
(isnull([7],0)+isnull([8],0)+isnull([9],0))/3 as Q3, 
(isnull([10],0)+isnull([11],0)+isnull([12],0))/3 as Q4
from 
(
  select month(Date) as TMonth, col, value
  from Table1
  cross apply
  (
    select 'Previous Data', [Previous Data]
    union all
    select 'Updated Date', [Updated Data]
  ) c(col, value)
)a
PIVOT
(
 AVG(value)
 for Tmonth in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
)pvt
```

Would someone please help me on how to achieve that?

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a little tricky, but here is the updated query that includes the YTD_WtdAvg column.  I added the year to the results because in order to do a wtd avg based on the # of days in a month and year, you have to know what year the data if for since Feb. has a different # of days depending on the year.

Based on the OP formula of `YTD = (Jan*(#Days in Jan) + Feb*(#Days in Feb) + ... + Oct*(#Days in Oct))/(Total days in a year)`, the query will still divide by the total # of days in the year, even if the today is not in Dec yet.

```
Select
pvt.TYear, 
pvt.FirstDayOfYear,
pvt.DaysInYear,
pvt.col,
[1] as Jan,
[2] Feb,
[3] Mar,
[4] Apr,
[5] May,
[6] Jun,
[7] Jul,
[8] Aug,
[9] Sep,
[10] Oct,
[11] Nov,
[12] Dec, 
(isnull([1],0)+isnull([2],0)+isnull([3],0))/3 as Q1, 
(isnull([4],0)+isnull([5],0)+isnull([6],0))/3 as Q2, 
(isnull([7],0)+isnull([8],0)+isnull([9],0))/3 as Q3, 
(isnull([10],0)+isnull([11],0)+isnull([12],0))/3 as Q4,
(
      case when pvt.TYear < year(getdate()) OR pvt.TYear = year(getdate()) AND month(getdate()) <= 1 then isnull(pvt.[1] * datediff(day, dateadd(month, 0, pvt.FirstDayOfYear), dateadd(month, 1, pvt.FirstDayOfYear)), 0) else 0 end 
    + case when pvt.TYear < year(getdate()) OR pvt.TYear = year(getdate()) AND month(getdate()) <= 2 then isnull(pvt.[2] * datediff(day, dateadd(month, 1, pvt.FirstDayOfYear), dateadd(month, 2, pvt.FirstDayOfYear)), 0) else 0 end 
    + case when pvt.TYear < year(getdate()) OR pvt.TYear = year(getdate()) AND month(getdate()) <= 3 then isnull(pvt.[3] * datediff(day, dateadd(month, 2, pvt.FirstDayOfYear), dateadd(month, 3, pvt.FirstDayOfYear)), 0) else 0 end 
    + case when pvt.TYear < year(getdate()) OR pvt.TYear = year(getdate()) AND month(getdate()) <= 4 then isnull(pvt.[4] * datediff(day, dateadd(month, 3, pvt.FirstDayOfYear), dateadd(month, 4, pvt.FirstDayOfYear)), 0) else 0 end 
    + case when pvt.TYear < year(getdate()) OR pvt.TYear = year(getdate()) AND month(getdate()) <= 5 then isnull(pvt.[5] * datediff(day, dateadd(month, 4, pvt.FirstDayOfYear), dateadd(month, 5, pvt.FirstDayOfYear)), 0) else 0 end 
    + case when pvt.TYear < year(getdate()) OR pvt.TYear = year(getdate()) AND month(getdate()) <= 6 then isnull(pvt.[6] * datediff(day, dateadd(month, 5, pvt.FirstDayOfYear), dateadd(month, 6, pvt.FirstDayOfYear)), 0) else 0 end 
    + case when pvt.TYear < year(getdate()) OR pvt.TYear = year(getdate()) AND month(getdate()) <= 7 then isnull(pvt.[7] * datediff(day, dateadd(month, 6, pvt.FirstDayOfYear), dateadd(month, 7, pvt.FirstDayOfYear)), 0) else 0 end 
    + case when pvt.TYear < year(getdate()) OR pvt.TYear = year(getdate()) AND month(getdate()) <= 8 then isnull(pvt.[8] * datediff(day, dateadd(month, 7, pvt.FirstDayOfYear), dateadd(month, 8, pvt.FirstDayOfYear)), 0) else 0 end 
    + case when pvt.TYear < year(getdate()) OR pvt.TYear = year(getdate()) AND month(getdate()) <= 9 then isnull(pvt.[9] * datediff(day, dateadd(month, 8, pvt.FirstDayOfYear), dateadd(month, 9, pvt.FirstDayOfYear)), 0) else 0 end 
    + case when pvt.TYear < year(getdate()) OR pvt.TYear = year(getdate()) AND month(getdate()) <= 10 then isnull(pvt.[10] * datediff(day, dateadd(month, 9, pvt.FirstDayOfYear), dateadd(month, 10, pvt.FirstDayOfYear)), 0) else 0 end 
    + case when pvt.TYear < year(getdate()) OR pvt.TYear = year(getdate()) AND month(getdate()) <= 11 then isnull(pvt.[11] * datediff(day, dateadd(month, 10, pvt.FirstDayOfYear), dateadd(month, 11, pvt.FirstDayOfYear)), 0) else 0 end 
    + case when pvt.TYear < year(getdate()) OR pvt.TYear = year(getdate()) AND month(getdate()) <= 12 then isnull(pvt.[12] * datediff(day, dateadd(month, 11, pvt.FirstDayOfYear), dateadd(month, 12, pvt.FirstDayOfYear)), 0) else 0 end 

)
 / pvt.DaysInYear
 as YTD_WtdAvg
from 
(
  select year(Date) as TYear
    , d.FirstDayOfYear
    , datediff(day, d.FirstDayOfYear, dateadd(year, 1, d.FirstDayOfYear)) as DaysInYear
    , month(date) as TMonth
    , col, value
  from Table1 t
  cross apply
  (
    select 'Previous Data', [Previous Data]
    union all
    select 'Updated Data', [Updated Data]
  ) c(col, value)
  cross apply 
  (
    select dateadd(year, datediff(year, 0, t.date), 0) as FirstDayOfYear
  ) d
)a
PIVOT
(
 AVG(value)
 for Tmonth in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
)pvt
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. Although it is lengthy, but it works! The only thing that I changed from your code is that instead of 'month(getdate()) <= 1', I used 'month(getdate()) >= 1', otherwise it will still add the rest of the parameters (say we're in Feb, month(getdate()) will still be less than 3 (Mac), so the logic doesn't go well. Other than that, your response works fine. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked for you. Yes, good catch on changing the month comparison to >= I will update the answer a little later when I get a chance.